# Verify that a Complex Vector space on $\mathbb R$ is a complex Normed Vector space in $\mathbb R$

Tags: functional-analysis

Verify that $\mathbb C^d$ with the function $||\cdot ||_1: \mathbb C^d \to \mathbb R$

$||x||_1:=\sum\limits_{k=1}^d |x_k|$,    $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_d)^T\in \mathbb C^d $

is a complex normed linear space.

I am a bit confused with how to answer this question as I dont know if I should be should be verify the vector space axioms or not.

If I was to just show that it was a linear space, How would I do this?

Would I have to let $y \in \mathbb C$ and then verify the normed space axioms?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to verify that the map  is a norm that is that:

- $||x|| = 0 \iff x=0$
- $||x + y || \le ||x|| + ||y||$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{C}^d$
- $|| \lambda x  ||= |\lambda| \  ||x||$ $x \in \mathbb{C}^d$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

It might be that you also need to show first that $\mathbb{C}^d$ is a complex vector space /linear space, in which case you have to verify that the axioms for a vectorspace hold. This works in basically the same way as it would for $\mathbb{R}^d$ in case that helps. Personally looking at the type of problem and the phrasing I would assume that you are allowed to assume as known that $\mathbb{C}^d$ is a complex vector space.

To verify that $\mathbb{C}^d$ is a $\mathbb{C}$ vectorspace one needs to check:

- $(\mathbb{C}^d,+)$ is a commutative group.
- $\lambda (\mu x) = (\lambda \mu) x$ for $\lambda , \mu \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x \in \mathbb{C}^d$.
- $1 \cdot x = x$ for  $x \in \mathbb{C}^d$.
- $(\lambda + \mu) x = \lambda x+ \mu x $ for $\lambda , \mu \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x \in \mathbb{C}^d$
- $\lambda ( x + y ) = \lambda x+ \lambda y $ for $\lambda  \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^d$

The operations are defined "as usual" so: $(x_1, \dots, x_d) + (y_1, \dots, y_d)=(x_1 +  y_1, \dots, x_d + y_d) $ and $\lambda (x_1, \dots, x_d)=  (\lambda x_1, \dots, \lambda x_d)$.

The argument is literally the same as for the real case. Indeed, it is the same for any field.

Comment: hey, thanks and yes I am meant to just show that it is a complex vector space/linear space, I am just confused because of the complex bit! How do I use this information to make a proof as I dont think I am meant to just show a normal norm

Comment: You do not need to use this explicitly at all. You can show that $K^d$ is a $K$ vectorspace for any field whatsoever. I will include some details though hold on.

Comment: I added the details. This verification is a lengthy slog. Again, I somewhat doubt you are expected to do this but it is not my call.

Comment: Ah thanks I was hoping that would be the case! Does the $1$ in $||x||_1$ mean anything? I can just introduce $y \in \mathbb C^d$ right? Sorry I am litterally just beginning a functional analysis course

Comment: The $1$ in the subscript here has no relevance for the argument; it has however a meaning  in the sense that generally for some $p \ge 1$ one can consider $ ||x||_p=(\sum_{i=1}^d |x_i|^p)^{1/p}$ the $p$-norm. Note the case $p=2$ especially in the real case is the "usual" euclidean norm. There is also the infinity norm defined as $\max_i |x_i|$. I am not sure what you mean by introduce $y \in \mathbb{C}^d$, but you certainly can use whatever element you want and consider $||y||_1$.

Comment: Thanks that's amazing and ha yeah that is what I mean, written more appropriately. Thank you :)

Comment: I am glad the information was useful. Good luck with the course.

Comment: Thank you and yes very useful! :)

Comment: I have tried to vote your question up but my reputation is not yet high enough. Cannot log into my old account either. Will try and remember to vote your answer up when I increase my "reputation".

Comment: Thanks. If you have issues with an old account see http://math.stackexchange.com/help/account for help.